# disabled="disabled" attribute does not disable the textfield in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textfields that I want to disable in particular scenario. I did that using jQuery like:

```
if (eligible) {
                    $(".email-address-field").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else{
                    $(".email-address-field").prop("disabled", true);
                }
```

Thsi works fine on all browsers except IE10 v, where I'm able to edit the disabled textfields like:
[image]

Here's what my code looks like when I inspect this textfield:

```
<input class="email-address-field" disabled="" type="text" value="xxx@mask.com"/>
```

**Note:** I have also tried using the following things but no success:

```
$(".email-address-field").prop("disabled", "disabled");
$(".email-address-field").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this issue or if there's any workaround for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing the class 'email-address-field' from your input markup. Hence, your selector would not find anything to disable. Are you sure this is working in any other browsers ?

Comment: @DinoMyte, it's there. I accidently removed it while pasitng it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the attribute `readonly` for 'disabling' text inputs.

`$(".email-address-field").prop("readonly", true);`

use `prop()` to apply the attribute (not `attr()`), and `removeProp()` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks @jzm, that worked like charm. Just one more question, the readonly attribute allows the focus into the textfield although nothing is editable. Is there a way to not allow the focus on the text field?

Comment: @CodeKaro Try setting both `disabled` and `readonly` to get that. I suspect it might not work in IE, though.